# couldn't find dso to load libjscexecutor.so caused by : dlopen failed: can't locate symbol "--emutls_get_address

Tags: android, react-native, error-handling

couldn't find dso to load libjscexecutor.so caused by : dlopen failed: can't locate symbol "--emutls_get_addressassist in diagnosing and resolving the issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTQvr.jpg)

Dear Team,

I have been encountering the same issue over the past few days. Despite my efforts to implement various solutions, I have been unsuccessful in replicating the problem. I have thoroughly reviewed and attempted all possible solutions, but the issue persists.

To provide more context, could you please specify the nature of the problem you're experiencing, any error messages received, or any unexpected behavior encountered? Additionally, if there are specific details about the code or environment that could be relevant, please share them. Your detailed information will greatly assist in diagnosing and resolving the issue.